# how i can integrate GWT widget in Vaadin 6(not found component - AbstractComponentState )?

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, widget, vaadin

I want to create a GWT widget and bind it to a component on the server. There is a good [wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+an+existing+GWT+widget), but it is for vaadin 7 (I use 6 version).

Corresponding to this manual I need several things:

- widget : client side
- AbstractComponent  : server side
- AbstractComponentConnector : connection component, organize work between widget and component
- AbstractComponentState : component which contains state for both objects(widget and component).

This for vaadin 7, in vaadin 6 I don't see **AbstractComponentConnector**(even analogs), **AbstractComponentState**

I can't find other manuals to do what I want. Please show components in vaadin 6 which I can use for achieving my goal.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the missing link:

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/gwt.html

As examples you can look at the vaadin 6 components available in the add-ons.
Usually the source is also available.

André